# C++: Is there a simple way of 'mapping' the hex colour `0xff2a2620` to a more readable string 'lovelyBrown'?

Tags: c++, hex, typedef, unsigned-integer, juce

I'm using the [Juce Framework](http://www.juce.com/) that has a `setColour` method like so:

`g.setColour (Colour (0xff2a2620));`

I instead would like to write something like more readable like:

`g.setColour (Colour (lovelyBrown));`, 'mapping' `0xff2a2620` to 'lovelyBrown'.

The method's prototype is:

`explicit Colour (uint32 argb) noexcept;` where `uint32` is:

`/** A platform-independent 32-bit unsigned integer type. */
typedef unsigned int                uint32;`

Juce has nice readable colour names already such as:

`const Colour Colours::tomato (0xffff6347);`, using a method to find the colour given a name:

`static JUCE_API Colour findColourForName (const String& colourName,
                                              const Colour& defaultColour);`

However, I don't want to modify or subclass their Colours class.  I am wondering if there is a simpler way of 'mapping' `0xff2a2620` to 'lovelyBrown'?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  A simple enum did the trick.  Not sure why I didn't do this straight away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you say Juce provides...

```
const Colour Colours::tomato (0xffff6347);
```

...you can add colours of your own:

```
const Colour lovelyBrown (0xff2a2620);
```

If you want a function to map from colour names to values at runtime, an easy and robust way is:

```
std::map<std::string, Colour> colourMap;
colourMap["lovelyBrown"] = lovelyBrown;
// add more here...
```

A slightly faster alternative is to have a contiguous array or `vector` of sorted colour names and use `lower_bound` to search.  If you're not sure how to do that, you probably shouldn't... ;-P.  (You'd either need to trust yourself/others to keep the list sorted in the source code, or do a runtime sort before first use, so there's a bit more risk/hassle+delocalisation respectively).

---

Note:

- a problem with using `enum class Colours` is that when you use the contained colour names, they *must* be prefixed by `Colours::`, so there's a discrepancy with the Juce-provided colour names:

```
    g.setColour (Colour (tomato));  // ok for provided colours
    g.setColour (Colour (Colours::lovelyBrown));  // oops, one of yours
```

- more generally, using `enum` or `enum class` makes the colours a distinct type, which has subtle consequences: e.g. you can't just stream them a la `cout << lovelyBrown` without writing your own `operator<<`, you can't invert the red component a la `lovelyBrown ^ 0xFF0000` etc. - again, these things can be done for the Juce-provided colours.

Comment: Thanks but as I said I don't want to edit the Juce classes since I pull from Github very often.  I used a simple enum

Comment: @DaveChambers: nothing in my answer suggests editing the Juce classes... why do you mention it?

Comment: Tony, I owe you an apology.  I simply added `g.setColour (Colour (Colour::lovelyBrown));` to my own file, included that file and it works like: `g.fillAll (Colour (lovelyBrown));`

That's perfect and the best solution.  Cheers!  Dave

Comment: @DaveChambers: no worries - glad if it helped.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use C++11 enums (that way your enum will be an `uint32_t`):

```
#include <cstdint>
enum class Colours : std::uint32_t {
    lovelyBrown = 0xff2a2620,
    lovelyOther = 0xff2a26FF
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it would have to be MyColours or similar to avoid clashing with the Juce class ‘Colours’ and I get an error `....No matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'MyColours' to 'juce::Colour'`

I answered it anyway myself with a simple enum the same time as you!

Comment: Of course, the naming was just an example. It's good you've found a solution anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum MyColour {
lovelyBrown = 0xff2a2620,
};
```

This works but I ended up following Tony's advise for a cleaner (and easy!) solution.  See his answer